# How do you expose a bulk create to django admin page users?

Tags: django, model, bulk

Let's say that, as part of an administrative process, thousands of values are created offline. These values are entered into a dead-simple model:

```
 class Foo(models.Model):
     value = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

I'd like to have a field on the model creation page that allows the user to enter (copy-paste) 1000 values in, and as a result, 1000 rows would be created in the table.

If I can add a text field to the model creation, all I have to do is parse out the values and call Foo.create for each. How would I add this free-form field, and how would I go about processing it when the user hits the Save button? ...or is there entirely a different way that I should be going about this?

Answer (score 6):

I realize my comment is more of an answer now.

Sure, why not? You hardly even need django for this. You could just create a `<textarea name="foo"></textarea>`, and in your view parse the data by line break.

Create a custom admin view via Admin.get_urls and write a custom view for your bulk create page.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls

Here's a copy and paste out of the live example for `get_urls`

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            url(r'^my_view/$', self.my_view),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls

    def my_view(self, request):
        # ...
        context = dict(
           # Include common variables for rendering the admin template.
           self.admin_site.each_context(request),
           # Anything else you want in the context...
        )
        if request.method == 'POST':
          for line in request.POST['bulk-create-paste'].split('\n'):
            Foo.objects.create(myfield=line)
        return TemplateResponse(request, "sometemplate.html", context)
```

## sometemplate.html

```
  <form method="POST">
    <p>Paste bulk create info.</p>
    <textarea name="bulk-create-paste">
    </textarea>
  </form>
```

Comment: I have no idea why but I got into so much trouble trying to create custom admin views. You not only answered my question but also saved my life in general. Thanks so much! Great and clean answer. I do suggest using `@method_decorator(staff_member_required)` so not just anybody can access the page and the `render` shortcut instead of `TemplateResponse`.